# Как кликнуть на onclick

Tags: python, selenium

На сайте есть ссылки без значения `href`.
Как мне на них кликнуть?
Ссылка:

```
<a onclick="funcjs['go-serf']('1992','666b88a2c584fee35ce3fa72b5a59fdf');return false;" title="тут разные ссылки" style="cursor:pointer;">Топовый букс! Присоединяйтесь!</a>

<a onclick="funcjs['go-serf']('6088','666b88a2c584fee35ce3fa72b5a59fdf');return false;" title="тут разные ссылки" style="cursor:pointer;">2000 рублей за пару минут!</a>
```

У ссылок общее только начало в `onclick`: `funcjs['go-serf']`.

Пытался так, но выдаёт ошибку:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@onclick,'funcjs['go-serf']')]").click()
```

Error:

> SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[contains(@onclick,'funcjs['go-serf']')]' is not a valid XPath expression.
> (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)

Comment: пишет что ошибка синтаксе xpath, если поправить то будет работать

Comment: `"//a[contains(@onclick,\"funcjs['go-serf']\")]"`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew подсмотрел [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171370/python-selenium-how-can-click-on-onclick-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там где вы посмотрели комманду есть:

```
br.find_element_by_css_selector("a[onclick^='fastener']").click()
```

где значек `^` означает совпадение с начала строки у Вас этого нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Согласно картинке нужно сделать:

```
"//a[@onclick^='funcjs['go-serf']')]"
```

(возможно придется экранировать вложенные одинарные кавычки)

Можно попробовать взять `xpath` предварительно в браузере если ссылки не меняются каждый раз:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ссылки всегда динамичные, меняются цифры на конце. Попробовал ваш вариант, но в конце сделал с помощью `starts-with' мне показалось это легко. Спасибо за расширенный ответ!

Comment: @Sherlock пожалуйста